# How to turn off Asset Pipeline on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

How to turn off asset precompilation on staging server on Heroku?

environments/staging.rb:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = false
```

Environment variable is set:

```
RAILS_ENV: staging
```

When pushing:

```
...Asset precompilation completed (30.65s)...
```

Rails 3.2.11

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845889/how-can-i-turn-off-asset-compilation-completely-on-a-rails-app-on-heroku