# How can I turn off asset compilation completely on a rails app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app which runs a service which has no assets. When I deploy, I see:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_3pneyggcg60ks/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_3pneyggcg60ks/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
       /tmp/build_3pneyggcg60ks/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
...
```

So I put this into my application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = false
```

But I still get the very same message when deploying.

How can I completely turn off asset compilation/handling on heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638200/how-to-disable-asset-pipeline-on-heroku) and [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally). It looks like the magic occurs in the `manifest.yml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

While precompiling assets, in Rails 3.x, you can prevent initializing your application and connecting to the database by ensuring that the following line is in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: that only controls if the app is initialized when precompiling, not whether or not it does precompile in the first place.

Comment: hmm, but now that i look at the accepted answer, maybe your suggestion will also work along with my config, because my config will actually be be picked up?